# stop deployment of people outside company email address - Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

Currently anyone with email address can deploy a code by firebase-tools 
i generally use firebase deploy

the challenge i have here is , i want to restrict people outside company email address to deploy code using the command firebase deploy .

Eg: company mail address : one@abc.com -> Allow 
outside company : one@xyz  -> Denie Deployemnt

Is this possible in firebase , i have read lot of document but nothing really helps me here !

I tried to do it with rules. file in firebase , but didnt find great solution

COMPANY EMAIL ADDRESS : one@abc.com

ACTUAL : one@xyz.com -> allowed

Expected : one@xyz.com - > Dont Allow since its not company mail addresss

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run `firebase deploy`, one must be signed in with an account that is a collaborator on that project.

If you don't want certain users to be able to deploy, don't add them as collaborators to the project.

If you want them to be collaborators, but not be able to deploy to Firebase Hosting, revoke their edit permission for Firebase Hosting.

Comment: is there a option where , this email address can be associated only with one project